# How to join to predicates together to get an attribute from the parent element based on two attributes and values from child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to get the "Date of Birth" node value only when the attribute "Benefit Type ID" is equal to "BEN13" **and** the attribute "Dependant of Benefit" is equal to "Y".

**XML**

```
<component>
<attributes name="FlexDependants">
    <attribute name="DataInstance">11</attribute>
    <attribute name="RowNumber">1</attribute>
    <attribute name="Date of Birth">Nov 11 1978</attribute>
    <component name="Allocation">
        <attributes name="Allocation">
            <attribute name="DataInstance">24</attribute>
            <attribute name="Benefit Type ID">BEN13</attribute>
            <attribute name="Dependant of Benefit">Y</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </component>
</attributes>
<attributes name="FlexDependants">
    <attribute name="DataInstance">10</attribute>
    <attribute name="RowNumber">2</attribute>
    <attribute name="Date of Birth">Oct 12 1984</attribute>
    <component name="Allocation">
        <attributes name="Allocation">
            <attribute name="DataInstance">23</attribute>
            <attribute name="Benefit Type ID">BEN13</attribute>
            <attribute name="Dependant of Benefit">N</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </component>
</attributes>
```

So basically I need to have two predicates in one statement, but I'm not sure how to do that..

I've tried:

```
/component/attributes/component/attributes/
attribute[@name='Benefit Type ID' and text()='BEN13'][@name='Dependant of Benefit' and text()='Y']/
../../../attribute[@name='Date of Birth']
```

^ But that doesn't work.

The problem is joining the two predicates together... they work fine individually but not together. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way (formatted for readability) :

```
/component
/attributes[
    component
    /attributes[
        attribute[@name='Benefit Type ID' and .='BEN13'] 
            and 
        attribute[@name='Dependant of Benefit' and .='Y']
    ]
]/attribute[@name='Date of Birth']
```

or this one using less nested predicate maybe easier to read :

```
/component
/attributes[
    component/attributes/attribute[@name='Benefit Type ID' and .='BEN13'] 
        and 
    component/attributes/attribute[@name='Dependant of Benefit' and .='Y']
]/attribute[@name='Date of Birth']
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two different attributes, so you can't specify both the conditions for just one:

```
 /component/attributes[attribute[@name='Date of Birth']]
                /component/attributes[attribute[@name='Benefit Type ID' and .='BEN13']]
                                     [attribute[@name='Dependant of Benefit' and .='Y']]
```